# java converting runnable into callable

Tags: java

Having:

```
T execute(final Callable<T> callable)
```

tried to overload with:

```
T execute(final Runnable runnable) {
  return ()->runnable;
}
```

Then invoked later with:

```
execute(()->somethingThatReturnsVoid())
```

Compiled fine and executed without any runtime exception.
Later discovered that `somethingThatReturnsVoid` was never executed.

Fixed by replacing

```
return ()->runnable;
```

with

```
return Executors.callable(runnable);
```

Can you explain how such code even compiles?
Then why no runtime exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lambda expression you are returning here does not actually execute the runnable:

```
return ()->runnable;
```

It just returns the runnable itself. Probably you meant:

```
return () -> runnable.run();
```